# referencing a string variable is giving me a string of numbers

Tags: java, android, string, reference

I am trying to reference a string stored in a .xml file, and every time i reference it I just get a string of numbers.

```
      if (Medals.medal_counter1 == 0) {
            Medals.medal_counter1++;
            victory.setMessage("you won " + R.string.medal01);

        }
                     victory.show();
```

Here is the stored string.

```
<string name="medal01">&quot;A medal&quot;</string>
```

The dialog I actually get is something more like this,

"you won 21310334567"

Any solutions?

Comment: Btw why was this question downvoted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are getting the string resource's ID. If you want to retrieve the actual string content you need to use `Context.getString(int resourceId)` method.

For instance, from inside an Activity:

```
victory.setMessage("you won " + getString(R.string.medal01));
```

Otherwise:

```
victory.setMessage("you won " + victory.getContext().getString(R.string.medal01));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
getResources().getString(R.string.medal01);
```

Answer (score 1):

**-** What you are referring to using `R.string.medal01` is an public static final integer value in `R.java` file.

**- Use below instead:**

```
victory.setMessage("you won " + getString(R.string.medal01));
```